# Translate Forums page title

Tags: 7, theming, nodes

I've tried with `preprocess_page`, `preprocess_forums` even changing `drupal_set_title` directly in forum.module but i can't get change that ugly page title "forums".

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the name of the (taxonomy) vocabulary that holds the names of the forums and groups.